# Login into different browser in same system , asking verfication code

Tags: login-errors

I'm having an account in  sales force developer edition , I'm working on  same account in Mozilla Firefox so whenever i logged in it never asks verification code in same browser but when i try to login in different browser like ( chrome) in the  same system it asks verification code , how to resolve this problem ,

Answer (score 2):

If you read the Security documentation of Salesforce, it is clearly stated when a user is asked for verification code.
[Security and the API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_concepts_security.htm)

Check point no. 5 of Security Token
[image: Security Token]

Your Browser stores some cookies that salesforce checks for every time you sign in. As Mozilla has those cookies you are not asked for verification code, but for Chrome you are asked for verification code.

As for how to avoid it, set IP based restriction, in such a scenario if your IP address is allowed salesforce won't check for cookies.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for support , I tried to my system , the problem will be rectified.

Comment: @ganesh Cheers no worries, and if this answer was what you were looking for then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This is all done on a per-browser basis. I can't say definitively how Salesforce does it, but this type of thing is almost always stored as a cookie in your browser. It is the same reason why you need to log into GMail in both Firefox and Chrome. That information is not shared across multiple browsers. There isn't anything to do here. It is just how it works when you want to use multiple browsers, you need to log in and verify your identity in each of them.

Comment: note that you can use the same browser once on your corporate network and once from home (with or without VPN) and still be asked for a verification code - so it is more than just per-browser

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, I give IP address range now its working